# RadScheduleView - EditAppointment in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, radscheduleview

I extended some fields in SqlAppointment Table and implemented IAppointment interface. I also customized EditAppointmentDialogStyle. In this style I added Custom DataTemplate with Some required Comboboxes.  When I Add or Edit Appointment - In DataTemplate Binding - Occurence.Appointment does not provide my extended properties. So how to set my extended properties while Newly Creating Appointment or while editing Existing Selected Appointment. Is there any way my ViewModel gets notified when any Appointment gets selected?

Thanks for your time and help..

Answer (score 0):

Where you put your additional properties which extend default IAppointment?
Check that you fire this.RaisePropertyChange when they changed.